# Stopping circular references in DataContract Serialiser

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

When serialising an object using Data Contracts I am hitting an issue with circular references. I know about using IsReference=true but I can't use this as I'm inheriting from object that I don't have control over. Is there any way to get around, can I count the times and exit, like a for break?

Answer (score 1):

Implementing a custom DataContractSerializerBehavior as suggested here: [Circular References and WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967603/circular-references-and-wcf) should fix it I think?

Updated for non-WCF:

The solution in the linked answer is based on using:

```
new DataContractSerializer(type, name, ns, knownTypes,
                          0x7FFF //maxItemsInObjectGraph,
                          false //ignoreExtensionDataObject,
                          **true** //preserveObjectReferences,
                          null //dataContractSurrogate);
```

Using this constructor should fix it I think.

Comment: I'm not using wcf, its just serialising using the DataContractSerializer. How could I implement the solution for this situation?

Answer (score -2):

You can use WeakReferences?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.weakreference.aspx